# Ionic NavController canSwipeBack() method returning false when it should return true

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this code inside an ionic page:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
console.log('swipeBackEnabled ' + this.navCtrl.swipeBackEnabled);
console.log('canGoBack ' + this.navCtrl.canGoBack());
console.log('canSwipeBack ' + this.navCtrl.canSwipeBack());
```

}

And it's returning true / true / false.

swipeEnabled is behaving exactly as expected since it's set in the App Config options in the app.module.ts file

But canGoBack() returning true is behaving exactly as it should. The page itself is navigated into through a navCtrl.push method and does, in fact, render the automatic back button in the ion-navbar component. When this button is clicked the app does indeed go back.

canSwipeBack() returning false is what I can't understand since according to the documentation it should return true if canGoBack() and swipeBackEnabled are true. And that's exactly the case.

I searched the whole project including compiled files for any accidental overrides of swipeBackEnabled to false and no such occurence exists anywhere in the project. Here's the app config.

```
IonicModule.forRoot(
  MyApp, 
  {
    swipeBackEnabled: true,
    mode: 'ios',
    platforms: {
      ios: {
        swipeBackEnabled: true,
        statusbarPadding: false,
      },
      android: {
        swipeBackEnabled: true,
        mode: 'md'
      },
      core: {
        mode: 'ios',
        swipeBackEnabled: true,
      }
    }
  }
),
```

Logging getViews() returns the following

```
(2) [ViewController, ViewController]

0: ViewController {_isHidden: true, _state: 3, willEnter: EventEmitter, didEnter: EventEmitter, component: ƒ, …}

1: ViewController {_isHidden: false, _state: 3, willEnter: EventEmitter, didEnter: EventEmitter, component: ƒ, …}
```

I'm testing this within a chrome browser and I've have restarted the server and browser numerous times.

Been trying to figure this out for a few weeks!

Comment: what do you get when logging `this.navCtrl.getViews()`? something relevant to the navigation you made?

Comment: Hi @kaddath, I get an array containing two ViewController objects

Comment: maybe a possibility that in this event, the page is not yet set to active? do you get the same results in `ionViewDidEnter`?

Comment: Placing the logging code ionViewDidEnter produces the exact output as with ionViewDidLoad (which is what's being used now)